# ASP.NET MVC strongly typed views or not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata, strongly-typed-view

What is the best practice - to use only strongly typed views without any parameters, that passes through the ViewData dictionary, or it's a not bad idea to use something like this in a view:

```
<%: (string)ViewData["helloMessage"]%>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should prefer strongly typed views. In some cases you need only one string like in your example, which doesn't belong to a model, then it is OK to use it. The other way is to encapsulate this variable into a class and pass the class to the view. The result would be a strongly typed view :-)

I personally don't like magical strings.

Comment: If you're only passing a string to the View, you don't need to create a special class just for the string. Instead, pass the string class itself as the model: `string a = ""; return View(a);` Also, if it's a string, you'd have to do `return View((object)a);` so that the string isn't confused for the View name - however, you can keep the View pointing to a string model.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using "magic strings"
But they are subject to typing errors.

In MVC 3 there is a dynamic object `ViewModel` in controller wich corresponds to a View object in view.
So you can assign `ViewModel.MyData="something";` in controller and use it in your view as `@View.MyData`
It is kinda a better way to go.

Having only strongly typed views benefits from compile time checking.
And it is up to you to decide.
Personally I use dynamic object.

Comment: The dynamic object approach in MVC 3 is awesome. I use it a lot, too ;-)